# Can't use "go" as variable name in Go

Tags: go

I think this is little weird, why does this code does not work?

```
  package main

  import "fmt"

  func main() {
     var i, j int = 1, 2
     k := 3
     c, python, go := true, false, false

     fmt.Println(i, j, k, c, python, go)
  }
```

Throws error

```
   # command-line-arguments
   .\compile64.go:8:13: syntax error: unexpected go, expecting expression
   .\compile64.go:10:29: syntax error: unexpected go, expecting expression
```

But this worked!

```
   package main

   import "fmt"

   func main() {
      var i, j int = 1, 2
      k := 3
      c, python, goo := true, false, false

      fmt.Println(i, j, k, c, python, goo)
   }
```

Is "go" a reserved word in Golang?

Comment: This is covered [in the Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/1), [in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords), and in [almost](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/LearnConcurrency) [every](http://www.golangbootcamp.com/book/concurrency) [book](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/10), [tutorial](https://golangbot.com/goroutines/), and [blog post](http://divan.github.io/posts/go_concurrency_visualize/) [ever written](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#goroutines) about the Go language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a keyword:

```
break        default      func         interface    select
case         defer        go           map          struct
chan         else         goto         package      switch
const        fallthrough  if           range        type
continue     for          import       return       var
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `go` is a reserved word to run [goroutines](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines), the language's main concurrency feature.